# Quiz with polish and english months

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I'm doing a simple quiz where you getting an question "How is called month xxx in polish?". I've done an array list with the months, random which taking the month from the list, but I don't know how can I check if the typed month is correct. Any ideas?
Here is my code with what I've done so far;

```
Random random = new Random();
            string[] miesiac = { "STYCZEŃ", "LUTY", "MARZEC", "KWIECIEŃ", "MAJ", "CZERWIEC", "LIPIEC", "SIERPIEŃ", "WRZESIEŃ", "PAŹDZIERNIK", "LISTOPAD", "GRUDZIEŃ" }; //months in polish
            string randommonth = (miesiac[random.Next(12)]);
            Console.WriteLine("Cześć, proszę powiedz mi jak jest " + randommonth + " po angielsku.");
            string answer = Console.ReadLine();
```

And here I am stuck because I do not know how to check if the answer is going to be correct or not. I know I will have to do probably another array list with the months in second language but I do not know how to check them then because it's all gonna be random.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Use the `Culture.DateTimeFormat` of each culture. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthnames(v=vs.110).aspx, then you don't need any dictionaries, or home declared look ups.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the indexes. Here is another approach to generate the month names:

```
var pl = new CultureInfo("pl-PL");
var en = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
var polishMonths = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => pl.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i)).ToArray();
var englishMonths = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(i => en.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i)).ToArray();
```

Now you can use `Array.FindIndex`:

```
int polishIndex = random.Next(12);
string randomPolishMonth = polishMonths[polishIndex];
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
int englishIndex = Array.FindIndex(englishMonths, m => String.Compare(answer, m, true) == 0);
bool isCorrect = englishIndex == polishIndex;
```

Comment: I like the usage of your select-statement, so I upvote

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need two dictionaries, one for polish and one for english months:

```
var polish = new Dictionary<int, string> = // ...
var english = new Dictionary<int, string> = // ...
```

Now you want to check for userinput

```
int i = random.Next(12);
string answer = Console.ReadLine();
if (answer == english[i]) Console.WriteLine("Correct");
```

or alternativly if you want to check if the answer is right polish month:

```
if (answer == polish[i]) Console.WriteLine("Correct");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in a lot of ways.
Here is one possible soulation:
Create Dic with ID and object that will store Month Name in English and in Polish.

```
Dictionary<int, MonthObj>;
```

Than random number and store it.
E.G:
 `int i = random.Next(12);`

Then get the value from The dictionary and check if the value is correct.